# Passing NSIndexPath to alertView clickedButtonAtIndex

Tags: objective-c, nsindexpath

I have a `UITableView` that loads data from `CoreData`. If I choose to delete a record from the table I use:

```
[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.recordList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
[self.tableViewSavedRecords reloadData];
```

and all is fine - the record is deleted and the table reloaded.

However some records are password protected and when such a record is chosen for deletion an alert appears to ask for the password:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Warning" message: @"This record has been password protected.\nEnter password." delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;
[alert show];
```

The `alertView clickedButtonAtIndex`:

```
NSString *enteredPassword = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];

if ([enteredPassword isEqualToString: savedPassword]) {
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.recordList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
    [self.tableViewSavedRecords reloadData];
}
```

The problem is `objectAtIndex:indexPath.row` is obviously not recognised in the `alertView clickedButtonAtIndex` section. How do I pass the `NSIndexPath` to `alertView clickedButtonAtIndex`?

I have tried declaring:

```
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
```

Then if the alert is triggered I have included:

```
selectedIndexPath = [tableViewPausedObs indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

Then in the AlertView Clicked:

```
[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject: selectedIndexPath.row];
[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

But it deletes the first row of the table, not the selected row.

Comment: `UIAlertView` is deprecated for a few years. Use `UIAlertController` which is block based and can capture the index path.

Answer (score 1):

You can get NSIndexPath of selected row anywhere like this

```
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this but I get th warning Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSIndexPath * _Nullable' to parameter of type 'NSManagedObject * _Nonnull' +. When I run the code the NSIndexParth is nil and crashes. See update.

Comment: Did you change this  `[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.recordList objectAtIndex: selectedIndexPath.row]];`?

Comment: Again, thanks. I hadn't added the .row which gets rid of the warning. However, it does not pick up the selected row and deletes the first row each time.

Comment: @RGriffiths Can you share screenshot of the tableview?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have decided to take a different approach which now works.